# Camerax delay in zoom in and out

Tags: android-studio, android-camerax

This maybe a weird question but I want to ask. I used CameraX in my application and for zoom in-out functionality, I used this code snippet:

```
val mListener = object :ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
        override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector?): Boolean {
            val currentZoomRatio = cameraInfo.zoomState.value?.zoomRatio ?: 0F
            val delta = detector!!.scaleFactor
            cameraControl.setZoomRatio(currentZoomRatio *delta)
            return true
        }
    }
    scaleDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(context, mListener)

binding.cameraView.setOnTouchListener() {
scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
return true
}
```

My question is when I zoom in and out, there is a 0-500 ms delay/latency between user touch and camera zoom in/out. Do you think this is the default behaviour of zoom in-out ?

Comment: The delay you see might have 2 parts: pinching and zooming, could you see which one is significant? use a button, or pre-set a value to zoom, see if there is difference?

Comment: Same issue for me. it's not up to pinching and zooming, I'm using a drag method and the delay is still present.  did you found something ?

Comment: Got the delay too. Some perfomance problem. Maybe try reassemble application in release mode(not debug).